# Why I can't clear a canvas with another empty canvas in HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

```
const buffer = document.createElement('canvas');
const context = buffer.getContext('2d');
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const screen = canvas.getContext('2d');
// buffer canvas and screen canvas have same width and height

// draw a circle on buffer canvas
context.beginPath();
context.arc(50, 50, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2);
context.fillStyle = 'rgba(156, 39, 176,1)';
context.fill();

// render to screen canvas (working)
screen.drawImage(buffer, 0, 0);

// clear canvas when click
canvas.addEventListener('click', () => {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, buffer.width, buffer.height);
  screen.drawImage(buffer, 0, 0);   // not working
  // only working with `screen.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);`
})
```

Like the code above, when using an empty canvas to clear another canvas, it's not working. (HTML only with `<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>` tag). Live Demo on https://jsfiddle.net/wjvtzng7/

Comment: In javaScript you only get a reference of your objects. if you have 2 of them, you have 2 exact the same object, if you change the one, then you changed the other too. That is the reason why your function not work like you think.

Comment: HTML5 only allow one `canvas` instance?

Comment: `buffer` and `canvas` refer to different `<canvas>` instances in above code

Comment: No that was not what I meant.
I mean in your JavaScript this is
const buffer = document.createElement ('canvas');
const canvas = document.getElementById ('canvas');
takes care of the buffer and canvas are both references from the same canvas, all changes to buffer or canvas, directly affect both variables, which is just a reference of the objects in there.

Comment: You can try to delete `screen.drawImage(buffer, 0, 0);` in `line 14` and see what happened. Live demo on https://jsfiddle.net/wjvtzng7/

Comment: However. . . `context.fillRect(0, 0, buffer.width, buffer.height);` will work. Strange.

Comment: `fillRect` doesn't truly clear `buffer` and `canvas` (It works in `line 14` too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we write down what you are doing, we get:

One offscreen canvas "*buffer*", and one visible canvas "*screen*".

Step by step,

- **draw a circle on "*buffer*"**
  At this stage

  - "*buffer*" represents a *circle*,
  - "*screen*" represents an *empty image (transparent pixels)*.
- **draw "*buffer*" on "*screen*" canvas**

  - "*buffer*" represents a *circle*,
  - "*screen*" represents a *circle*
- **clear "*buffer*"**

  - "*buffer*" represents an *empty image (transparent pixels)*
  - "*screen*" represents a circle
- **draw "*buffer*" on "*screen*" canvas**

  - "*buffer*" represents an *empty image (transparent pixels)*
  - "*screen*" represents a circle

It seems your confusion comes from the last bullet. But this operation could be rewritten as

- **draw an *empty image (transparent pixels)* to an image that represents a *circle*.**

This indeed does nothing... at least in normal *compositing* mode *source-over* where drawing a fully transparent pixel does nothing. See [alpha-compositing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing) for more reads about it.

So if you wish to clear your "*screen*" canvas, you indeed need to clear it using the `clearRect()` method of the `screen` context. <sub>There are other ways, but don't use them.</sub>

---

---

Now, I felt I should also point out that there are other [compositing modes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation) than *source-over* available, and that what you expected can actually be done with one of these: *copy*.

```js
const buffer = document.createElement('canvas');
const context = buffer.getContext('2d');
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const screen = canvas.getContext('2d');

// initialize
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
buffer.width = window.innerWidth;
buffer.height = window.innerHeight;
// draw a circle
context.beginPath();
context.arc(50, 50, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2);
context.fillStyle = 'rgba(156, 39, 176,1)';
context.fill();

// render to screen canvas
screen.drawImage(buffer, 0, 0);

// clear canvas when click
canvas.addEventListener('click', () => {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, buffer.width, buffer.height);
  // only the next drawing operation on screen will be visible
  // everything else will get cleared out
  screen.globalCompositeOperation = "copy";
  screen.drawImage(buffer, 0, 0);
  // set back to default mode
  screen.globalCompositeOperation = "sourc-over";
})
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```